# camel rest producer - failed to create Producer

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

I try to create a simple http request in apache camel with maven.
I'm using camel version 2.24.3

My code for the camel route looks like:

```
package org.example;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class ConsumeRest extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration().host("localhost:5000/");
        from("timer:scheduler?period=6000")
                .to("rest:get:hello/");
    }
}
```

My dependencys in the pom.xml are:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The error

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route
>   route2: Route(route2)[[From[timer:scheduler?period=6000]] ->
>   [To[res... because of Failed to create Producer for endpoint:
>   rest://get:hello/. Reason: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException:
>   Cannot auto create component: null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by myself, you have to add `.component("http")` to the rest configuration.

```
package org.example;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class ConsumeRest extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration().host("localhost:5000/").component("http");
        from("timer:scheduler?period=6000")
                .to("rest:get:hello/");
    }
}
```